# Select a table view cell programmatically: selectRowAtIndexPath vs setSelected

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I often need to set table view cells to an initial selected state for which I use the following code:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
   animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setSelected:YES];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

I am using `selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath` and `setSelected:YES` at the same time, because I do not fully understand which of both ways are the preferred way to select a cell programmatically.

Which one of the statements should I use and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the method you want to use is `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`. Usually, you should leave management of cell state to the table view. In case of selection, it stores and maintains a set of selected index paths, so the proper row will remain selected after a different cell is reused for it. There's also no need to call both methods, it is simply redundant.

Comment: Thank you, @Nicky! After using `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` I would then reload the table and set the checkmark in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` depending on the cell's selection state (`isSelected`)?

Comment: Well, I usually store checkmarked item in a separate property, it feels more explicit. So, in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you do the following: reload two rows, the one previously checkmarked and the one user clicked (without animation), select the clicked row (also without animation), and then deselect it animated so you get a nice visual effect. All done by calling table view's methods.

Comment: Additional selection is needed because the cell will lose it after being reloaded. You may just set accessory type there and be fine without reload/selection, though I prefer not to duplicate any part of the cell configuration logic. Who knows, maybe tomorrow I'll be using fancy custom checkmarks or some other crazy stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: viewModel.item, section: viewModel.section)

self.categoryCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)

if let cell = self.categoryCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SubcategoryCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SubcategoryCollectionViewCell {
    //...//
}
```